# Do I need "in" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions, ellipsis

> We'll just hang around the bridge, not (in) the actual residence.

Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the negated phrase to have the meaning of **in**, then **yes**, you do need the preposition in the sentence.

If you do not place the preposition there, people will understand that the preposition *around* was elided and that that one is the preposition you imply in the second part of your sentence. So, this phrase:

> We'll just hang around the bridge, not the actual residence.

Will be understood like to have the same meaning as this phrase:

> We'll just hang around the bridge, not **around** the actual residence.

So, if the meaning you are trying to convey is that they will hang **in** the residence and **not around** it, you need the preposition to be expressed:

> We'll just hang around the bridge, not **in** the actual residence.